# How to find out how much RAM a docker run execution consumed at maximum?

Tags: docker, memory-management, ram

I have created a new docker services and am determining its required resources. Since applying the RAM to a new service is greedy--saying the container can have 8GB of RAM it will get them--I don't want to waste the cluster's resources.

Now I am trying to find out how much RAM a docker run took at its peak.

For example, I created a httpie-image (for the rightfully paranoid, the [Dockerfile is also on dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/k0pernikus/httpie-docker-alpine/~/dockerfile/) that I execute via:

```
docker run -it k0pernikus/httpie-docker-alpine HEAD https://stackoverflow.com/
```

I know that there is a [`docker stats`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/runmetrics/) command, yet it appears to show the *current* memory usage, and I don't really want to monitor that.

If I run it after the container ended, it will show `0`. (To get the container id, I use the `d` flag.)

```
$ docker run -itd k0pernikus/httpie-docker-alpine HEAD https://stackoverflow.com/ 
132a93ffc9e297250b8ca37b2563aa2b5e423e146890fe3383a91a7f26ef990c
$ docker stats 132a93ffc9e297250b8ca37b2563aa2b5e423e146890fe3383a91a7f26ef990c
```

it will show:

```
CONTAINER                                                          CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
132a93ffc9e297250b8ca37b2563aa2b5e423e146890fe3383a91a7f26ef990c   0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           0
```

Yet how much RAM did it consume at maximum?

Comment: try `docker run -itd... ; docker stats $(docker ps -lq)` or `docker run -itd --name mycontainer...` and in another terminal, you launch as soon as possible `docker stats mycontainer`

Comment: Check [cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr:

- Enable memory accounting
- `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/${CONTAINER_ID}/memory.max_usage_in_bytes`

---

[Docker uses `cgroups` under the hood](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/#metrics-from-cgroups-memory-cpu-block-io). We only have to ask the kernel the right question, that is to `cat` the correct file. For this to work memory accounting has to be enabled (as noted in the docs).

On systemd based systems this is quite straight forward. Create a drop-in config for the docker daemon:

```sh
systemctl set-property docker.service MemoryAccounting=yes
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker.service
```

(This will add a little overhead though as each time the container allocates RAM a counter has to be updated. Further details: https://lwn.net/Articles/606004/)

Then by using the full container id that you can discover via docker inspect:

```
docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" $CONTAINER_NAME
```

you can get the maximum memory used:

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/${CONTAINER_ID}/memory.max_usage_in_bytes
```

The container has to be running for this to work.

Comment: It appears that `sudo service docker restart` suffices. No reboot required.

Comment: Maybe even `sudo service docker reload` suffices.